# How to design the app in generic way for RSS Reader

Tags: android, iphone, rss, rss-reader

I have question about RSS reader applications like Pulse(android/iphone app). In this kind of applications how does the app understand different kinds of the RSS feeds.. 
Does all the RSS information from different sources have similar pattern like title, source url, image.
I have tried to see some RSS info, but I could find image tag in some but not all.. can anyone please tell me how should I design the app  for different feeds in a generic way so that my app should have title, image.
Correct if Im wrong in understanding the RSS and app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulse have contacts with publishers. So (for some feeds) it gets images from them directly.

RSS image tag is usually image for whole feed. If you want to show pictures from feed items you'd look at enclosure, media:thumbnail and media:content tags. And for most feeds you need to get image from post content (looking for <img> tags, links to youtube/vimeo, etc.).